# How to differentiate various NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using Multiple `NavigationController` in my app

```
let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

Assigning tag as

```
navViewController.navigationBar.tag = 10
```

& fetching as

```
if navigationController?.navigationBar.tag == 10 {
```

Instead `navigationBar.tag`,  Can't we differentiate using navViewController reference or `navigationController.tag` ?

Comment: Is the use case that you are trying to figure out from the view controller who is the navigation controller that owns it, and configure based on that? In that case, why not set a property on the view controller itself?

Answer (score 2):

Using tags to differentiate between navigation controllers is ok. To make the code more readable and to avoid any possible mistakes you can define tags as constants or enums and check for the constant value.

The other way is subclassing UINavigationController for each case and checking for corresponding class:

```
if let navController = navigationController as? CustomNavigationController {
  //your code
}
```

Subclassing adds to the boilerplate and makes the project larger. So if you do not need any customisation on each navigation controller you can keep using tags.